# Is there any property in the GroupBox that indicates that nested controls were checked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im using GroupBox Control on my Form Page(WinForms).

The GroupBox contain five controls(RadioButtons).

Any idea if group box control contains property that inidactes if any of the button inside the control were checked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No since GroupBoxes are not meant for just RadioButtons. Its a general container control. To check if anything is checked, you could do in one line with `Linq`.

```
bool anyChecked = gb.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(rb => rb.Checked);
```

Or you could create your own extension method with it and call it easily if its often re-used.